# ColdFusion ORM how to update without dropping?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a persistent entity in ColdFusion and I need to update a property

```
property name="createdDateTime" ormtype="date";
```

to

```
property name="createdDateTime" ormtype="timestamp";
```

before, I use to delete the table then reload ORM. However,now I have data in my table I cannot just delete it. Is there anyway I can update this field in ORM without dropping the whole table?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to just change the property and do ormReload(). Try it in a test environment first but the ormtype is not directly tied to the database type.

Answer (score 1):

in your Application.cfc

```
this.ormSettings.dbCreate = "Update";
```

Anyway, in your case (date -> timestamp), the underlying SQL type should be the same (at least in SQL Server, which is `datetime`)

Comment: I assumed datetime and timestamp in SQL are different, right?

Comment: @Niklas yes, but `ormtype="timestamp"` uses `datetime` in SQL server if you used `dropcreate` to create your table, if I'm not mistaken.  So you just need to set `dbCreate` to `update`, or even `none`, and `ORMReload` without touching your DB.  Then ORM will start persisting the time as well.